# Poisson Process.

Tags: probability, poisson-process

The number of applications forms a Poisson process $(N_t,t \geq 0)$ of rate $\lambda = 6$. Let $M_t$ be the number bad applications in the time interval $[0,t]$ with rate equal to $\frac{2}{3}$. Arrivals of bad applications are independent. Considering possible values of $N_t$, compute the probability that $P(M_t = m)$.

Comment: Are you saying each application has a probability of being bad of $\frac23$ or of $\frac{2/3}{6}=\frac19$?

Comment: Some versions of this question have appeared here before. It's a standard exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname{E}}$
\begin{align}
& \Pr(M_t=m) \\[8pt]
= {} & \e(\Pr(M_t = m\mid  N_t)) \\[10pt]
= {} & \e\left( \binom{N_t} m \left( \frac 2 3 \right)^m \left( \frac 1 3 \right)^{N_t-m} \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & 2^m \e\left( \binom {N_t} m \left( \frac 1 3 \right)^{N_t} \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & 2^m \sum_{n=m}^\infty \binom n m \left( \frac 1 3 \right)^n \Pr(N_t=n) \\
& \text{(This starts at $m$, not at $0$, because} \\
& \phantom{\text{(}} \text{the probability is 0 when $n<m$.)} \\[8pt]
= {} & 2^m \sum_{n=m}^\infty \binom n m \left( \frac 1 3 \right)^n \frac{e^{-6t} (6t)^n}{n!} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{2^m (2t)^m e^{-6t}}{m!} \sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{(2t)^{n-m}}{(n-m)!} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{(4t)^m e^{-6t}}{m!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2t)^k}{k!} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{(4t)^m e^{-6t}}{m!} \cdot e^{2t} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{(4t)^m e^{-4t}}{m!}
\end{align}
So the marginal distribution of $M_t$ is Poisson with expected value $4t.$